# Slimscroll bar very slow in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, slimscroll

I am using the slimscrollbar plugin. It is working fine in Web Browser, but its very slow in mobile browser.

Any solution to increase the speed that work for mobile?

Comment: Did you get it working faster? touchScrollStep is not working for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you have used the slimscrollbar plugin found here: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll you may want to change the setting of "touchScrollStep" to round 50.

The default is 200 which is pretty slow, less than 200 is faster and -200 is inverted scrolling "natural".

Some code:

```
$('#slimscroll').slimScroll({
   size: '5px',
   height: '600px',
   alwaysVisible: false,
   touchScrollStep: 50
});
```

Cheers,
david

Answer (score 1):

Change the touchScrollStep does not work for me.
I've modified the touchmove event, and remove the divided by touchScrollStep. The original code is:

> var diffX = (touchDifX - e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX) / o.touchScrollStep;
>
> var diffY = (touchDifY - e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) / o.touchScrollStep;

now the touchmove event code like this which works in my case:

```
      me.on('touchmove', function(e){
      // prevent scrolling the page if necessary
      if(!releaseScroll)
      {
          e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
      }
      if (e.originalEvent.touches.length)
      {
        // see how far user swiped
        var diffX = (touchDifX - e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
        var diffY = (touchDifY - e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);

        // scroll content
        scrollContent(diffX, diffY, true);
        touchDifX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        touchDifY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
      }
    });
```