# Fullpage.js : why the scrollOverflow option is not smooth on mobile?

Tags: fullpage.js

I  implemented fullpage.js and it works perfectly. Currently I'm trying to use the option  `scrollOverFlow = true` to scroll inside a section when this section has a too high height.

On computer this is awesome, but when I launch my website on my mobile, the scrolling inside a section is not smooth and slow.

Is it normal ?

[EDIT] This is smooth on Firefox but not chrome on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Because Fullpage.js is using slimscroll.js for inner page scroll, and this js plugin's option default `touchScrollStep: 200` is too slow. You can refer to "[Slimscroll bar very slow in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334827/slimscroll-bar-very-slow-in-mobile-browser)".

My solution is to open the slimscroll.min.js, and change the default of `touchScrollStep: 200` to `touchScrollStep: 50`